# Is it is allowed to have secure transaction from iPhone native app

Tags: iphone

What I know that we can't develop a native app in iPhone which uses secure transaction(banking, purchasing etc). If we want to do so, we need to use Browser in app.

Just let me know if I am correct. Is there in link which clarifies my concern.

Thanks
SD

Comment: What do you mean by "secure transaction"? HTTPS, SSL, TLS?

Comment: In web we use Authorize.Net or PayPal or similar payment gatway to perform transaction(buy product). Is this is possible in iPhone app

Answer (score 1):

You Can Develop a native app in iPhone which uses secure transaction...

you can use NSURL and NSURLRequest classes to implement Web Services and to make it secure you have to implement  ssl web service... to consume ssl Web service you just need to add one line

```
[NSURLRequest setAllowsAnyHTTPSCertificate:YES forHost:host];
```

Answer (score 0):

You can certainly implement HTTPS transfers trivially in your iPhone app. You mentioned "purchasing", though, and there you may run into a problem. The iPhone store agreement states that any purchase of additional content for your application has to be through Apple's in-app purchase API.

I don't know if that precludes real-world purchases (like using you app to buy some physical article that'd be shipped to a customer). What are you trying to do, exactly?

Comment: yes, I am trying to create app like Amazon. where people need to enter Creadit card detail and then can buy any item.Also can I create an app for some bank, where user can view account, transfer money to a/c, etc....

Comment: Doesn't Stanza allow you to buy books from several ebook sellers without using in-app purchasing? I'm pretty sure I've seen other examples, too.

Comment: I guess we cant use any payment getway?